# Hashtag to trigger a jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have received help earlier in another question about some jQuery transitioning and I got my website to behave properly, but now I need to get a bit deeper into this jQuery transitioning...

I need a particular effect/transition to happen based on the hashtag that is written in the address bar. This is the code provided by the other question by **pckill**:

```
$('.nav').on('click', 'li', function(){
var id = $(this).data('id');

var breadcrumbs = document.getElementById('breadcrumbs');
breadcrumbs.innerHTML = 'IMGit &raquo; <span class="capitalize">' + id + '</span>';

var current = $('#inner').find('[data-page=' + id + ']');
if (current.hasClass('hidden'))
{
    current.css('marginLeft', '-200%');
    $('#inner > div').not(current).animate(
        {marginLeft: '100%'},
        'fast',
        function(){
            $('#inner > div').not(current).addClass('hidden');
            current.removeClass('hidden');
            current.animate({marginLeft: '0%'}, 'fast');
    });
}
});
```

**And this is the HTML:** http://pastebin.com/pu7jmefC

Let's say, for example, I link someone to `http://mywebsite.com/index.php#remote`, I want the user to be transitioned **with** jQuery to the proper div. The approach above works perfectly with the menu I have, but I want to be able to share the URL with someone and they'd still be able to get **directly** to the proper div.

I think the code above needs some altering to make it do what I seek, but I unfortunately, I'm not that good in Javascript/jQuery.

I guess we'd have to touch the code somewhere around here: `$('#inner > div').not(current)`.

I know we have `window.location.hash` to work with hashtags, but I have no idea how to put it to use in the code above.

Ideas?

Comment: need to see some of your nav html in order to understand relationship between the hash and the nav elements

Comment: Sorry about that. Added a pastebin url to the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to check the hash on page load and perform an action accordingly, that's really simple. First of all you need to move the logic of transitioning to a div into a separate function, say `transitionToDiv`:

```
function transitionToDiv(id) {
    var current = $('#inner').find('[data-page=' + id + ']');
    if (current.hasClass('hidden'))
    {
        current.css('marginLeft', '-200%');
        $('#inner > div').not(current).animate(
            {marginLeft: '100%'},
            'fast',
            function(){
                $('#inner > div').not(current).addClass('hidden');
                current.removeClass('hidden');
                current.animate({marginLeft: '0%'}, 'fast');
        });
    }
}
```

And change the click event (the code in your question) to:

```
$('.nav').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    var breadcrumbs = document.getElementById('breadcrumbs');
    breadcrumbs.innerHTML = 'IMGit &raquo; <span class="capitalize">' + id + '</span>';

    transitionToDiv(id);
}
```

Now, to transition to a div on page load based on the address hash, simply add these lines at some point after page load:

```
var id = window.location.hash.substr(1);
transitionToDiv(id);
```

Comment: It's almost working. The issue now is that if I go to `http://myweb.com/index.php#remote`, it doesn't load the proper div automatically, I have to refresh the page and then it works. So direct linking isn't working. Here is how the JS looks like: http://pastebin.com/XyesUUpL

Comment: @Aborted: I think you have it the wrong way around. If you link the page to somebody, it will work. It is if you manually type "#remote" in the URL while **already on the page** that nothing will happen, because the page doesn't reload when the hash segment changes. I don't think you have to worry about people manually typing new stuff into the URL though, but if you are, read up on the `hashchange` event.